# Yii Framework.how to use multiple form in one view

Tags: php, ajax, yii

Is there a complete example/solution for the following requirement in yii?

1.Collect data from user in one page but in different form for the same model.

eg. I have a table abc with the following columns

column1,column2,column3,column4

and need view for it like

First form
column1(Field is required.)
column2
savebutton

Second form(need last inserted id of first form)
column3
column4
savebutton

2.Collect data for other model but in same above view

third form
colum5
colum6
savebutton

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

if all 6 columns are on 1 page, you could just wrap all the columns in the form tag?

Comment: it is client requirement collect data into separate form.

Comment: well there you go, separate form it is and separate views for each form

Answer (score 0):

You can use tabs menu in Yii for your form.In tabs just put your form elements,in another tab put another elements of form 
for reference just check [this link](http://www.eha.ee/labs/yiiplay/index.php/en/site/widget?view=tabs_simple)

Comment: I have issues with validation and submit in this scenario.

Comment: If I submit data of form one is ok.When I submit second form with last inserted id then new record inserted instead of update.